# The output from mysql won't show correctly on table

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I use simple AJAX to display data from database. But, when i run it, only 1 data show on my table, the rest of data show outside from my table. Am i missing something ?

I use same code from my standar Bootstrap table and it show data into my table correctly, but not this one.

My PHP file

```html
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "tata_kota1";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT * from laporan_gini";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

echo "<table border='1'>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Nomor</th>
<th><b>tipe variabel</b></th>
<th><b>variabel turunan</b></th>
<th><b>nama atahun</b></td></th>
<th><b>turunan tahun</b></td></th>
<th><b>data_content</b></td></th>
<th><b>vertical variabel</b></th>
</tr>
</thead>";

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        {
            echo "<tbody><tr>";
            echo "<th>".$row['id']."</th>";
            echo "<td>".$row['nama_variabel']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['nama_variabel_turunan']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['nama_tahun']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['nama_turunan_tahun']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['data_content']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['nama_item_vertical_variabel']."</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
            
        }
        echo "</tbody></table></table>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is you have an extra set of `{}` inside your `while` and so the `echo "</tbody></table></table>";` is inside the `while`, not outside it. Try this:

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<tbody>";
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th>".$row['id']."</th>";
        echo "<td>".$row['nama_variabel']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['nama_variabel_turunan']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['nama_tahun']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['nama_turunan_tahun']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['data_content']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['nama_item_vertical_variabel']."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</tbody></table></table>";
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to write tbody before the while loop.